# Sharing embed youtube private video using youtube API

Tags: youtube-api

I have made a video private https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqKtBWC3RrU because i dont want everyone to see those video.

Is there a way to create youtube embed link with the API for private video so that I can share that link to anyone and they can view it using the link.

Comment: it will be useful to recognize your question ,if you post your code

Comment: The API wont be able to create a link for a private video you would need access to see it.

Comment: why private ? you can make it public but not referenced unless you have the link